# pyodbc.ERROR An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm processing a data from SQL server and writing it back after some processing.

The processing takes a bit long (4-5 hours) so when i start to load I get an pyodbc.ERROR An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I would like to inquire on the following:

- How to keep the connection alive? Where can the timeout be configured?
- When you define the engine in SQL Alchemy does it automatically connect you already to the database?
- Faster way to export pandas dataframe to SQL Server

Below is sample of my flow:

```
    #read
    data = pd.read_sql_table(src, engine, schema=myschema)

    #step 1
    data = myfunc1(<args>)

    #step 2
    data = myfunc2(<args>)

    #step 3
    data = myfunc3(<args>)

    #write

    data.to_sql(tgt, engine, schema , index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of [Disconnect Handling - Pessimistic](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic):

```
engine = create_engine(<your_connection_string>, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm sorry but I'm not too familiar with pooling how do I implement this when my db is MS SQL? I was going through the link you provided but it seems it's calling something that's only for Postgres? Please do correct me if I'm wrong.